# Automatically referenced typescript definition

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to create a typescript definition file that will be automatically referenced by all compiled typescript files?

Context:

I am setting some global configuration variables server-side and setting them as global window properties.
I would like to have a definition file that would define the types of those variables as an extension of window object. I would like this file (something like global.d.ts) to be automatically referenced by all compiled scripts without specifically writing ///<reference .... in each file.

I am currently using angular 6 cli to compile the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found out the answer :)
I just needed to add the global.d.ts to the "includes" section in tsconfig.app.js and all was good to go :)

Now every file has it referenced :).